# Compiler can't choose between generic extension methods with different where conditions

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Here is code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
  public interface MyBaseClass { }

  public interface MyClass1 : MyBaseClass { }

  public interface MyClass2 : MyBaseClass { }

  public interface Filter { int Id { get; set; } }

  public interface Filter1 : Filter { }

  public interface Filter2 : Filter { }

  public static class DbExt
  {
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereHistory<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<Filter1, bool> expr) where T : MyClass1
    {
      Console.WriteLine("WhereEntityHistory");
      return source;
    }
  }

  public static class DocExt
  {
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereHistory<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<Filter2, bool> expr) where T : MyClass2
    {
      Console.WriteLine("WhereEntityHistory");
      return source;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IQueryable<MyClass1> query1 = (new List<MyClass1>()).AsQueryable();
      query1 = query1.WhereHistory(h => h.Id == 0);

      IQueryable<MyClass2> query2 = (new List<MyClass2>()).AsQueryable();
      query2 = query2.WhereHistory(h => h.Id == 7);
    }
  }
}
```

This code is compiled with error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'ConsoleApplication8.DbExt.WhereHistory(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Func)' and
>   'ConsoleApplication8.DocExt.WhereHistory(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Func)'

Call is not ambiguous because of where conditions. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to use them with full names?

Comment: Why not just do DbExt as `IQueryable<MyClass1>` and DocExt as `IQueryable<MyClass2>` seeing as you are restricting them to that anyway and not truly generic? See my answer for more info.

Comment: This extension methods will be called on interfaces, inherited from MyClass1 and MyClass2.

Comment: But MyClass1 and MyClass2 are interfaces anyway? So any derived types along the inheritance hierarchy will still work?

Comment: Fixed previous comment

Comment: Why are you doing this with extension methods and not within the classes that implement the interfaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic constraints are not part of a function's signature, so in order to distinguish between them you'd need to call them as static methods (or give them different names).

> The method type inference algorithm considers only whether the method type arguments can be consistently inferred from the types of the arguments.

Source: [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx)

Comment: Great @D Stanley, it's nice to see an article of Eric Lippert related to this.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints on generics are [not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to filter by `where T : MyClass1` why not just remove the generic and use

```
   public static IQueryable<MyClass1> WhereHistory(this IQueryable<MyClass1> source, Func<Filter1, bool> expr)
```

Comment: This is not the same if you have classes derived from `MyClass1`

Comment: @Maarten who said it was the same? plus he just needs a explicit cast to make it work again.